# How does Mighty Signal do this animated background?

Tags: javascript, background

How would one replicate a similar effect for the background in their header? (The data thing)

http://www.mightysignal.com/

I don't think it's a video but correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a video. It's an HTML5 canvas animation probably done with JavaScript to track the mouse position and do that animated bit you see.

All of the JS is minified on the site so it makes it tough to point to a specific bit of code that provides the effect on the canvas.

You can check these out in the future by right clicking and site and choosing "Inspect Element" in Chrome / Firefox. IE has a similar feature too.